# How to use Equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, equation

I'm working on Matlab Code for Lagrange Interpolation.

My problem is working with equations.

For solving Lagrange you need to find the `Li(x)'s ( L0(x) to Ln(x) )` first:

e.g. for `L0(x)` we've got:

```
L0(x) = (x-x1) (x-x2) (x-x3) / (x0-x1) (x0-x2) (x0-x3)
```

which for an example it would be:

```
l0(x) = ( x^3 - ( 2 * x^2 ) + 2x ) / 6
```

which is an equation.

I write the code but it won't accept the variable **`z`** (which i used instead of `X` ) and it tells:

> "Undefined function or variable 'z'."

Which is certainly correct cause it's a variable and not a data but how could i use or write this?

Comment: Try doing `syms z` then try your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB by default does not like undefined variables (as do most programming languages!)

You have two ways of solving your problem: numerically solving Lagrange "by hand" -- i.e. with functions like `ode45`, or trying to do it symbolically. This means that you either have to explicitly define `x` as a symbolic variable -- with `syms x` and use the [symbolic maths toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/symbolic/?refresh=true), or, alternatively, use a numerical scheme and something like [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html).

If you want to define a function in MATLAB, you need to plonk a definition into a separate file and save it.

**For example:**

```
function out = ellZero( x, a )
    x0  = a(1); x1 = a(2); x2 = a(3); x3 = a(4);                % SET Constants 
    out = (x-x1).*(x-x2).*(x-x3)./((x0-x1).*(x0-x2).*(x0-x3));  % RET Expression
end
```

If you want to learn more about how MATLAB handles `functions` and 'sub-`functions`', have a look at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html). You might also be interested in the [Partial Differential Equation Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot.  symbolic maths toolbox worked properly but just one other question, what is the use of point after Braces like (x-x1).  ?

Comment: By default, variables in matlab are essentially n-dimensional tensors(!) -- they can be multidimensional matricies. That's why Matlab is called MATLAB -- It's short for 'Matrix laboratory' (or was, at any rate). 

If `x` is a scalar, `x.*x` and `x*x` are identical. If it isn't, however, `x*x` is the matrix product, and `x.*x` is essentially the element-wise inner product. For example, if `x=[1 2 3]`, then `x.*x` is `[1 4 9]`, `x*x` is not defined (and `x*x'` is 14). 

It's generally good practice to use element-wise multiplication and division unless you explicitly want matrix multiplication.